Mapping fields from custom object which have a lookup relationship with another custom object
When I give this formula, I always receiving a error
/lightning/o/Task/new?defaultFieldValues=WhatId={!Issues__c.Id},Facility__c={!Issues__c.Facility__c},Asset_del2__c={!Issues__c.Asset_Name__c}
My Asset_del2__c in Task and Asset_Name__c in Issues are in lookup relationship with Asset object. In my case when Issue is created with facility and Asset name values, I want to add it to task. When adding it in task I want the task field facility and asset to be autopopulated or mapped from the Issue object

Sorry, but I'm not getting the question. What is the exact error text? Do you receive this error while trying to create a field of type "Formula" "Text" on the Issues object? Or a custom button? What do you want to achieve with this formula? From your last sentences it appears to me you're not sure, if your lookups (and formulas) are well designed at all. If so, StackExchange is often not a good place to get an answer, because so much depends on context knowledge.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to [edit] your post to include the error message.  Also, the del2 indicates the field was deleted and then un-erased.  You should change the field's API name to remove del2 to make it cleaner.

so it looks like you are doing Lightning URL hacking. What error are you getting?  Please use [edit] to amend your post. If used in a button, it must be on an Issues__c object
